# Bios password protection

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, bios, encryption

I have my system on drive C: and also I have all my important folders on drive D:.  I want to lock this drive with a password.  Any advice?

Comment: BIOS protection is totally different from folder&drive protection. Please make it clear in your question.

Answer (score 8):

Go get [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

Feature-List (taken from the site):

- Creates a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real disk.
- Encrypts an entire partition or storage device such as USB flash drive or hard drive.
- Encrypts a partition or drive where Windows is installed (pre-boot authentication).
- Encryption is automatic, real-time (on-the-fly) and transparent.
- Parallelization and pipelining allow data to be read and written as fast as if the drive was not encrypted.
- Provides plausible deniability, in case an adversary forces you to reveal the password:
    Hidden volume (steganography) and hidden operating system.
- Encryption algorithms: AES-256, Serpent, and Twofish. Mode of operation: XTS.

There's no easy solution for "securing a harddisk or a single partition with a password". You could, of course use a BIOS password, but this won't stand a chance if the attacker is in front of the PC (CMOS reset jumper f.e.).

Some harddisks do offer the functionality of a password, but as far as I know, the BIOS will have to support it, too. There are also multiple problems with it, forgetting the password will turn the harddisk into a nice brick, and in most cases you can crack it as easy as the BIOS password.

Comment: +1: Don't screw around with BIOS passwords, or other mickey-mouse crap. Encryption is the right way to keep your files secure.

Comment: @satanicpuppy: True, especially since a BIOS password won't help a thing If I'm in front of the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want BIOS password protection or do you want file system protection? If you want the latter, update the title of the question and then check out [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/). If it's the former, update the body of your question and then reboot your PC and check out the BIOS menu.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with the TrueCrypt route as suggested by Bobby.

Though if you want to be lazy and aren't really that concerned and you have a Professional version of Windows, you can try using their password protected and encrypted directories.